# Update p:growl from @ApplicationScoped bean listening on p:socket

Tags: jsf, primefaces, websocket, growl

I have application scoped bean that is listening to web-socket. When message is received I would like to update growl. But something like below doesn't work because it is not in request / response time. It is possible to do this?

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("growl");
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Message", "value"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is send a PrimeFaces push event from the bean to all attached clients on a general websocket shared by all clients. In that event you send a message like in the [PrimeFaces push notify](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/notify.xhtml) example

```
 public void send() {
    EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
    eventBus.publish(CHANNEL, new FacesMessage(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(summary), StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(detail)));
}
```

And then in the page show that message

```
<p:growl widgetVar="growl" showDetail="true" />
<p:socket onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/notify" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleMessage(facesmessage) {
        facesmessage.severity = 'info';

        PF('growl').show([facesmessage]);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks i try that but i only get 101 switching protocol from server.

Comment: Then try to find the cause of that. It works for me. Might be that CHANNEL is not defined of you or something else..

Comment: It is interesting because I have same error (101) even on example Counter and after some time (couple of minutes) it started working.