# Primefaces Dialog Framework and Growl messages

Tags: jsf, iframe, primefaces, jsf-2, dialog-framework

I'm using Primefaces 6.1 Dialog Framework. I'm wondering if there's a way to use a general growl for nested dialogs.
I could use a growl in one of the child dialogs but it displays the messages inside the boundaries of the iframe and not on the top-right corner of the window.

Here's an example:
main.xhtml > dialog1.xhtml > dialog2.xhtml

So, I'm in main, then I open dialog1 to view some data and then dialog2, which is kind of a tiny CRUD page.
When there's an error in this last page, I want to display the error message on the top-right corner of the WINDOW (not the iframe), just like it would do in the main page.

I don't know if it's a bug/issue or I'm just dumb, but I'm running out of ideas. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

(I can't provide the code now, but if it's really neccesary i'd edit this a put a simple example).

Comment: Use something like https://stackoverflow.com/q/29491403/4478047 and just use the generic html/javascript way pf accessing a javascript function in a parent window

Comment: @Kukeltje i'll try it tomorrow and tell you the results. Thanks for the quick response!